# Python tkinter Doubling Checkboxes

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working on a Synthesizer inside Python for a school project and currently have a really troublesome issue. I have a Stack of Checkboxes which mark when a note is played and on which pitch inside a sequencer. My Problem is that whenever I open two Oscillators inside my synthesizer and put in the Values inside the checkboxes, the checkboxes duplicate their value over the multiple windows, but don't do it for the actual sequence, as in I have two lists with correct values, but the values aren't properly displayed inside the window.

To Replicate the Problem hit "new Oscillator" then click on "Arpeggio", do this a second time and click any Checkbox on the Arppeggio Windows

I know this might be a confusing explanation, but I'm going to link the complete code in the bottom so you can try it out and might know what I'm talking about.

The problem occurs inside the "Arpeggio" Class

```
import numpy                                # used for Waveform Calculation
from functools import partial               # used for Command Combining
from tkinter import *                       # used for GUI
from tkinter import ttk                     # used for GUI
from tkinter import filedialog              # used for GUI

np = numpy                      # Simplifying Libraries
tk = ttk                        # Simplifying Libraries
fd = filedialog                 # Simplifying Libraries

root = Tk()

#StartupFunction
def StartUp():
    print("")
    print("Starting Startup") 
    app = App(root)                 # Initializing GUI
    
    print("Finished Startup")
    main()
    ("Exiting Startup")

#Main Program Function
def main():
    print("Executing Main")
    root.mainloop()
    print("Finished Main")
    return 0

class Oscillator():
    pass

class App(tk.Frame):
    OscillatorWindowList = []
    OscillatorList = []
    SoundInputArrayList = []
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        root.title("PySynth")
        root.geometry("984x300")
        root.resizable(False, True)
        root.maxsize(984,720)
        btnNewOscillator = Button(root,text="New Oscillator",command=self.NewOscillator,relief=RIDGE,bg="#2d2d2d",fg="white")
        btnNewOscillator.place(x = 8, y = 8+128)

    def NewOscillator(self):
        print("AddingOscillator")
        self.OscillatorList.append(Oscillator())
        self.SoundInputArrayList.append(SoundInputArray(root,len(self.OscillatorList)-1,len(self.OscillatorList)-1))
        print(self.OscillatorList)
        self.OscillatorWindowList.append(OscillatorGUI(root,self.OscillatorList[len(self.OscillatorList)-1],len(self.OscillatorList)))

    def EXIT(self):
        root.destroy()
    
#$SoundInputArray
class SoundInputArray():
    actv = []
    CheckbuttonList = []
    CheckButtonFreq = []
    i=0
    ButtonCount = 32
    VolumeSlider = None
    btnArpeggio = None
    Arpeggio = None
    hasArpeggio = False
    LFO = None
    ArpeggioList = [(0,0)]

    def __init__(self,master,oscillatorCount,number):
        btnArpeggio = Button(master,text="Arpeggio",command=self.OpenArpeggio,relief=RIDGE,bg="#2d2d2d",fg="white")
        btnArpeggio.place(x = 8, y = (1+oscillatorCount)*48 +128 )

    def OpenArpeggio(self):
        if self.Arpeggio == None:
            self.Arpeggio = Arpeggio()

    def GetArpeggio(self):
        return self.Arpeggio

#$Arpeggio
class Arpeggio():
    SoundValueList = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        GUI = Toplevel(root)
        GUI.title("Arpeggio")
        GUI.geometry("480x320")
        GUI.resizable(False, False)
        GUI.configure(bg="#171717")
        self.SoundValueList = np.arange(0,16)
        self.DrawUI(GUI)
        self.ClearList()

    def DrawUI(self,frame):
        Button(frame,text="display", command= self.PrintSound, width=11,bg="#171717",).place(x = 4, y = 4)
        Button(frame,text="empty", command= self.ClearList).place(x = 96, y = 4)
        y = 1
        x = 1
        checkbuttonList = []
        for y in range(1,13):
            for x in range(0,16):
                updatecommand = partial(self.UpdateList,x,y)
                checkbuttonList.append(Checkbutton(frame, variable=self.SoundValueList[x], onvalue=y, offvalue=0,command = updatecommand))
                checkbuttonList[len(checkbuttonList)-1].place(x = x*24 + 96, y= y*24 + 8)
    def ClearList(self):
        for i in range(0,16):
            self.SoundValueList[i] = 0
    def UpdateList(self,x,value):
        if (self.SoundValueList[x] == value):
            self.SoundValueList[x] = 0
        else:
            self.SoundValueList[x] = value
        self.PrintSound()
    def PrintSound(self):
        print(self.SoundValueList)
    def GetList(self):
        print(self.SoundValueList)
        return self.SoundValueList

StartUp() # Initiate Program
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You don't need to share your whole code, just share enough to reproduce the issue and remove all other code. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details.

Comment: It is because in `Arpeggio.DrawUI()` you passed integer value to `variable` option of checkboxes which will created a common `IntVar` for same value.  Try changing `self.SoundValueList = np.arange(0, 16)` to `self.SoundValueList = [IntVar() for _ in range(16)]`.

Comment: Thank you so much @acw1668! Yes that actually worked!